# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `attendee_id`

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create an association between a User model and an Attendance model in which an attendee_id references a user. The association is a many to many relationship between users and concerts. The join table attendances has two fields
`:attendee` and `:concert`.

seed.rb file:

```
require 'faker'

Concert.destroy_all
User.destroy_all
Attendance.destroy_all

15.times do
  Concert.create(band: Faker::RockBand.name, venue: "#{Faker::LordOfTheRings.location}", date: Faker::Date.forward(rand(30)), start_time: "8:00 PM")
end

5.times do |number|
  User.create(first_name: Faker::Name.first_name, last_name: Faker::Name.last_name, email: "#{number}@email.com", password: "password")
end

concerts = Concert.all
users = User.all

15.times do
  Attendance.create(attendee: users.sample, concert: concerts.sample)
end
```

Here are the models:

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User" 
  belongs_to :concert
end
class Concert < ApplicationRecord
  validates :band, :venue, :date, :start_time, presence: true
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, presence: true
  validates_format_of :email, with: /@/
  has_secure_password
  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attendee_id
  has_many :concerts, through: :attendances
end
```

Here are the migrations:

```
class CreateAttendances < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :attendances do |t|
      t.references :attendee
      t.references :concert, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateConcerts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :concerts do |t|
      t.string :band
      t.string :venue
      t.datetime :date
      t.time :start_time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please remove snippets and use proper code format instead (use th **{ }** button). Also, please share the code that produces the error (most likely, your controller).

Comment: Indicates one of your associations is wrong.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks for pointing that out. I have not created any controllers yet, I am just trying to seed the database.

Comment: @JoshBrody I can not figure out what is it that I am doing wrong. In the attendance model, I set the attendee to reference the user.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are no `attendee_id` column

`bundle exec rails db:reset` (same as `db:drop` + `db:create` + `db:migrate` + `db:seed`)

And for tests `bundle exec rails db:test:prepare`

If it`s not solve the problem, i think, we need moar stacktraces)

Answer (score 0):

I run `bundle exec rake db:drop` and then I created the database `bundle exec rake db:create` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I was then able to seed the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change `t.references` to special alias `t.belongs_to`.
It worked for me with Rails 5.2.1